# Extract values from a comma delimited file when delimiter is coming in data itself

Tags: shell, unix

Hi I have a requirement where I want to extract values from a comma delimited file. The problem arised when file delimiter comes as a data value. All the values will come in a pair of single quotes and if some value is not coming then it will be blank.
Example:

```
cat file1.dat
'Data1','DataA',,',',,'2','0','0'
'Data2','DataB','X','D','3','1','2'
```

In the script I am doing the following

```
while read line
do
F1=`echo $line | cut -d"," -f1`
F2=`echo $line | cut -d"," -f2`
F3=`echo $line | cut -d"," -f3`
F4=`echo $line | cut -d"," -f4`
print $F1
print $F2
print $F3
print $F4
done < file1.dat
```

Present output:

```
'Data1'
'DataA'

'
'Data2'
'DataB'
'X'
'D'
```

Desired Output:

```
'Data1'
'DataA'

','
'Data2'
'DataB'
'X'
'D'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution assumes that you have a character that doesn't appear in the input.  Say the character `|` doesn't appear in `file1.dat`, then the following would yield the desired result:

```
$ sed "s/,',/,'|/" file1.dat | cut -d, -f1-4 --output-delimiter=$'\n' | tr '|' ','
'Data1'
'DataA'

','
'Data2'
'DataB'
'X'
'D'
```